# Topic of the Week

Tags: discussion, topic-of-the-week

(Copied from [Space.SE](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/373/25), modified to fit here)

One of the things that Stack Exchange in general has found effective is to devote a week to a specific topic in which members of the site feel is lacking. For instance, Arqade will frequently have a topic week to discuss a new game coming out, or Science Fiction and Fantasy will ask more questions about Star Wars. They encourage the entire membership to focus asking questions on a particular topic, often with the use of a single tag, especially if we feel like the site should be including more of those types of questions. This has been going on the Space.SE community for about 2 months, and has been highly successful.

I am planning on setting this up, at least for a while, for this site. Each Sunday, a reputable community member will pick a highly voted answer to this question for which to select as the topic of the week. This will keep going as long as there is interest from the community. During that week, we encourage all of the active members to ask at least one question on that specific topic. Do research if you have to. In the end, we will be able to fill out this site, to include things which we don't have enough activity yet.

Please give a single tag per question which you feel is underrated, and give an explanation of that tag to the group, so everyone can understand enough to start asking questions. Linking relevant Wikipedia articles can be of help, or other useful starting points for research. Finally, if you have a request for a specific week, then please include it in your answer. For instance, if there is a significant anniversary, a major event, etc, then it seems logical we should have a topic of the week built around that subject.

Topics-

- **November 17- November 23, 2013**- [propagation](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/propagation)
- **November 24- November 30, 2013**- [emergency](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emergency)
- **December 1- December 7, 2013**- [diy](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diy)
- **December 8- December 21, 2013**- [contest](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contest) (Two weeks due to late start.)

Comment: @AdamDavisKD8OAS: This topic needs the featured tag to be listed easily on the front page.

Answer (score 4):

[propagation](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/propagation) - questions dealing with [the propagation of radio signals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_propagation).

Possible subtags within this include (but are not necessarily limited to):

- [line-of-sight](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/line-of-sight)
- [ground-wave](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ground-wave)
- [ionosphere](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ionosphere)
- [troposphere](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/troposphere)

Some related Wikipedia articles (beyond the main one, linked above):

- [Radio propagation model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_propagation_model)
- [Fading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fading)
- [Free-space path loss](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free-space_path_loss)
- [Skywave](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skywave)
- [Earth-Ionosphere waveguide](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth-Ionosphere_waveguide)
- [Tropospheric propagation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tropospheric_propagation)

Comment: You forgot that we've already covered [ionospheric propagation on the planet Mars](http://ham.stackexchange.com/q/421/29). Having crossed that frontier, what's left to explore? ;)

Answer (score 3):

[diy](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diy) - questions dealing with handmade/homebrew radios and radio accessories (`D`o `I`t `Y`ourself).

Possible subtags within this include (but are not limited to):

- [glowbug](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/glowbug)

Some related Wikipedia articles:

- [Amateur radio homebrew](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amateur_radio_homebrew)

Comment: glowbug is vacuum tube equipment, right? (Hint hint.)

Answer (score 2):

[contest](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contest)

Dealing with any contest rules, explanations, etc.

- [How is a "Generally Inactive" ham determined for Field Day GOTA?](https://ham.stackexchange.com/q/225/13)

Answer (score 2):

[emergency](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emergency) - questions dealing with emergency communications of any form.

Possible subtags within this include (but are not necessarily limited to):

- [ares](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ares)
- [races](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/races)
- [raynet](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/raynet)

Some related Wikipedia articles:

- [Amateur Radio Emergency Service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amateur_Radio_Emergency_Service) (ARES)
- [Radio Amateur Civil Emergency Service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_Amateur_Civil_Emergency_Service) (RACES)
- [Radio Amateurs Emergency Network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_Amateurs_Emergency_Network) (RAYNET)

Other resources:

- [ARES Handbook](http://www.arrl.org/ares-manual)

Comment: beware of [tag:whacker]

Answer (score 1):

[repeater](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/repeater) - questions dealing with ham radio repeaters and their operation/use.

Possible subtags within this include (but at not necessarily limited to):

- [digipeater](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/digipeater)

Some related Wikipedia articles:

- [Radio repeater](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_repeater)

Answer (score 1):

[satellites](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/satellites) - questions dealing with amateur radio transmissions involving space-based entities.

Possible subtags within this include (but are not necessarily limited to):

- [so-50](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/so-50)
- [ariss](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ariss)
- [space-station](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/space-station)

Some related Wikipedia articles:

- [AMSAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMSAT)
- [OSCAR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSCAR) (Orbital Satellite Carrying Amater Radio)
- [Saudi-OSCAR 50](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saudi-OSCAR_50) (SO-50)

Other resources:

- [Amateur Radio on the International Space Station](http://ariss.rac.ca/oindex.htm) (ARISS)

Answer (score 1):

- [antenna](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/antenna) with sub-tags such as below

  - [balanced-antenna](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/balanced-antenna)
  - [omni-antenna](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/omni-antenna)
  - [directional-antenna](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/directional-antenna)
  - [mobile-antenna](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mobile-antenna)
- [transmission-line](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transmission-line) with sub-tags such as below

  - [coax](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coax)
  - [flat-ribbon](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flat-ribbon)

Comment: Antennas seem to get a lot of attention. Also, please add one suggestion per answer, to make keeping track of them easier.

Comment: Agreed with @PearsonArtPhoto; antenna-related questions can be interesting, but they don't need more attention right now. If anything, IMO we could use a little more diversity!