# Topic of the Week #1: Nov 17-23: radio propagation

Tags: discussion, topic-of-the-week

During the week of November 17 through November 23, 2013, the [Topic of the Week](https://ham.meta.stackexchange.com/q/100/29) for Amateur Radio Stack Exchange is:

[propagation](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/propagation)

**Questions dealing with [the propagation of radio signals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_propagation).**

*We encourage all members to ask questions relating to the Topic of the Week,* although of course other questions that are on-topic for the site are welcome as well.

Possible subtags within this include (but are not necessarily limited to):

- [line-of-sight](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/line-of-sight)
- [ground-wave](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ground-wave)
- [ionosphere](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ionosphere)
- [troposphere](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/troposphere)

Some related Wikipedia articles (beyond the main one, linked above):

- [Radio propagation model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_propagation_model)
- [Fading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fading)
- [Free-space path loss](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free-space_path_loss)
- [Skywave](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skywave)
- [Earth-Ionosphere waveguide](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth-Ionosphere_waveguide)
- [Tropospheric propagation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tropospheric_propagation)

**To suggest further Topics of the Week, please go to [Topic of the Week](https://ham.meta.stackexchange.com/q/100/29) on Amateur Radio Meta.**