# Is there a Plan for driving more traffic to the site?

Tags: discussion

I've noticed the steady decline of the number of unique users / day over the last few weeks.  The holidays (at least in the US) aside, it seems like we need about 5x as many users/questions/answer to achieve a healthy critical mass.

I've tried promoting this site to (ham) friends of mine and posted to the web sites of my clubs.  I haven't paid much attention to the meta side of the sight and wondered if this has been discussed and if so what came of it.

Answer (score 4):

It might be a good idea to try to get the site featured in the amateur radio magazines (the ones made of dead trees). QST, the local ones, etc. I could write a little article on the Finnish amateur radio magazine, they're always looking for news articles.

Maybe we could draft up an example article that could be translated and adapted for local magazines.

Comment: Excellent idea! The local club I belong to is always begging for articles, but many of the local members have also contributed to QST in the past.

Answer (score 3):

Site popularity is driven to a high degree by how often it comes up in search engine searches (e.g. Google).

So the more questions with answers here, even if they duplicate stuff explained on other web sites, and as long as most the answers here are mostly correct, will likely help make this site more popular.

Answer (score 2):

The [Topic of the Week](https://ham.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100/topic-of-the-week) initiative is one way in which we're attempting to help stimulate site activity, but we're always open to suggestions for other ways to increase traffic.

Comment: That may help once they are on the site, more content means there's more of a chance that they will find stuff they can use.  I was talking about getting people *to* the site.  As I mentioned, I've tried to talk it up locally, for instance.

Comment: The two are somewhat linked - getting people to the site doesn't help much if they don't stick around, and people who find value in the site are more likely to spread it via word of mouth.

Answer (score 2):

Suggest preparing a PowerPoint presentation on "Web-based Elmering" for participants to take to local ARES, Red Cross, SATRN and other meetings, said meetings always being hungry for new discussion topics.  High points would include the Stack Exchange model, epic questions, epic answers, funny questions and answers, and the advantages of being able to Elmer over the web when one has time.

Once that's polished, then contact the ARRL for wider distribution, and even perhaps a story in their magazine; ditto for RAYNET and other organizations in the Anglosphere.

Answer (score 2):

Traffic has gone up when more questions and answers have been made, in short when the site has more activity and new content.

Asking questions and answering them is going to be our biggest draw in the short run and the long run, so whatever else we might try, we should really make sure we don't lose focus on the primary use of the site.