# How can we improve the activity on this site?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, recent-activity

I don't know about you all, but I'm quite grateful to have this site as a resource. I feel like it is starting to enter a decline, which has me worried. I see fewer good questions being asked, and less activity. We are even down to only 2 moderators! What can we do to help this site to grow?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a Plan for driving more traffic to the site?](http://meta.ham.stackexchange.com/questions/121/is-there-a-plan-for-driving-more-traffic-to-the-site)

Comment: You are probably right, but I think it might be worth talking about again.

Comment: Isn't the Right Thing™ to bump the old post? But yes, weak opinion, only one vote.

Comment: Happened to be reading [this on Meta SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/258974/159388) which talked about getting involvement from (_in the context of that proposal,_ SE staff) who “know something about community development”. Maybe we need an outside viewpoint. I think I know some things about How People Interact Online, but I know I don't know a good way to solve _this_ problem.

Comment: By the way (this is tangential but you did mention it) if we actually need more moderators I'd be happy to help.

Comment: I notice that _this week,_ we've had good-quality questions from 5 or so new users.

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto Unless one just resigned or was removed, [we have three moderators](https://ham.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310/please-welcome-your-new-moderators). :-)

Comment: @MikeWaters That wasn't the case 2 years ago...

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto I said what I did because I saw that you (or someone) edited your post 2 days ago.

Comment: @KevinReidAG6YO I thought that it was the Right Thing™ to bump the old post today.

Answer (score 6):

Let me give a few interesting tidbits. It turns out that site views are up, but questions are down. Thus, I think we are attracting people to the site, but no one seems to want to stick around for more than just getting the answer to their question.

I think we need to see if we can do something to increase the number of good questions on this site. Perhaps we could go with a theme, as we have tried to do in the past?

Comment: Theme? I don't know what you mean.

Comment: Make a weekly topic which you try to ask lots of questions on that subject.

Comment: I just found your November 2013 [post about this](https://ham.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100/topic-of-the-week). Interesting.

Answer (score 3):

The original question was from 2015, but since there is recent interest:

My evaluation of the current state of things (mid-2017) is that *everything is fine and we don't need to do anything*. I look at the history of activity on the site and I see seasonal cycles and **an overall consistent upward trend.**

I recommend against specific promotional activities. (The cost is that we annoy people the way all advertising annoys people sometimes, and look like we have some incentive to "drive eyeballs to the site" or such.) It's not broken; don't fix it.

Comment: What are the pros and cons of promoting the site vs. not promoting it?

Comment: @MikeWaters I added a few words.

Comment: Well, it's been 4 years. Do you feel the same way? My opinion has always been that we need more activity, especially after Glenn W9IQ went back to eham.net. We lost a valuable technical expert.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't much of an answer, but I think that the low participation rate is a natural consequence of the design of all the Stack Exchange sites.  Since most questions that might occur to people have been answered already, the rate of questions being asked has declined, and a lot of the questions that do get asked are of lower quality.  This tends to turn off people who might otherwise be attracted to the site.  It doesn't help that amateur radio is a mature field, and so new topics evolve slowly.

That's how I see it anyway; my opinion plus $2 will buy you a cup of coffee...

Comment: I dunno. Other sites are far more active.

Answer (score 1):

[**Area 51**](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/43029/amateur-radio) lists hundreds of formerly very active folks that are no longer active for some reason. Someone wanting to increase the activity might consider encouraging some to come back. Possibly, find out if there was a reason for leaving that no longer exists. (I asked PearsonArtPhoto (a former moderator) some time ago (in another meta post), and I doubt whether he is interested.)

---

[**eHam.net** has a *Links* page](http://www.eham.net/links/) for listing ham-radio related websites there. You just pick the correct category, add the URL, and write a brief and appropriate description about it. If someone wants to do that, I suggest you include *a question-and-answer site* in the description. Perhaps some text from the main [tour page](https://ham.stackexchange.com/tour) would be appropriate.

Comment: The  reason a site like STACK EXCHANGE gets a low rating is that it is not fancy apparently.  So be it!