# Please welcome your new moderators

Tags: discussion, moderators

I'm Pops, a Community Manager at Stack Exchange. I'm here today to announce two new moderators for your community, replacing two long-serving mods who have stepped down. Please welcome:

[image: MikeWaters]
[image: ScottEarle]

Please join me in welcoming Mike and Scott to the mod team, and in thanking PearsonArtPhoto and Amber for their service!

Comment: Well, I have a lot to read and learn before I can do much moderating. :-)

Answer (score 6):

Welcome!

It's pretty quiet around here, so moderation doesn't involve a lot of volume of work — I always feel the tricky bit is the judgement calls, particularly around the quality of answers and the topicality of questions.

Let's go dust off that moderation chat room a bit…

Answer (score 3):

Good to see some new mods. This site just became too much for my current time, but I welcome the new moderators! Congrats!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks! I have been into radio for a long time (33 years and counting), and have been hanging out on here for three years (long beta!). Most of my contributions so far have been in flagging questions/answers, and retagging questions.

Question tags are a pet peeve of mine. It frustrates me when a question is posted with no consideration of how it should be tagged. Tags are there to assist other people who are trying to find questions that might be relevant to them. It doesn't take much to think "I am asking a question about propagation, so let me add the 'propagation' tag". That way, we have all questions about propagation grouped together.

That's my pet peeve anyway. Expect to see me continuing to retag lots of questions from now.

Comment: Hello Scott, I haven't given a lot of thought to tags, but it looks like you have some good thoughts on this to share. I look forward to working with you and Kevin. I've always thought that he is an outstanding moderator. :-)

Comment: _My_ pet peeve is when tags exist and are used but aren't _useful_ categories. As you can probably tell from my meta posts!

Answer (score 1):

Besides PearsonArtPhoto and @rclocher, who else were moderators on hamSE in the past?

Comment: I was never a moderator, I just took the review queues seriously for a while.

Comment: @rclocher3 It's not up to moderators to decide, but might you be interested in being a mod someday?

Comment: I'd consider it.

Comment: BTW the other moderator was @Amber.