# Later this year, hamSE may no longer be a beta site. What will happen?

Tags: discussion, beta

Per [this answer in a related question](https://ham.meta.stackexchange.com/a/403/8717), we ***might*** come out of beta in late October.

- What will happen then?
- Will there any advantages, etc. of no longer being a beta site?
- We need to prepare a logo or avatar. What should it look like?

As was mentioned in a [comment](https://ham.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/401/beta-status-as-of-february-2020/403#comment684_403), *it might not be automatic*.

- What can we do (if anything) to ensure that it happens?

Maybe not much. :-)

Answer (score 4):

Nowhere has anyone said that we will automatically come out of beta after 7 years. There was a one-off removal of beta status from its that were 7 years old or older, and it was implied that as well as all the other criteria for coming out of beta a new criterion was added that says: "Still be a viable site after seven years".

That does not equate to "all beta sites that have made it to the seven-year point will automatically immediately have the beta tag removed".

It's a little disingenuous to post a link to *your own speculative post* saying that we might come out of beta on a particular date, and hold it up as evidence that we might come out of beta on that date.

Anyway, in the spirit of unfounded speculation (I use Apple products, so I guess I am used to that?), here we go:

- What will happen then? If they remove our beta status, then the site will no longer say 'beta' on it.
- Will there any advantages[sic]? Yes! We will no longer have 'beta' on the site.
- We need to prepare a logo or avatar. Or both? We would need a favicon, and a proper logo. What will it look like? I think that would be best put to the users of this site, and we should ask it as a question, which we could pin for a while and allow people to send their own suggested logos - maybe offer a bounty (of 500 or something?) for the person who suggests the best one?

Now for the one that is not too difficult to answer:

- How do we ensure that it happens? I say ... we use the site more! Get as many hams to use the site as possible, and if people do ask questions we are friendly and helpful, and we all try to answer as many questions as we can!

Comment: 'Get as many hams as possible' has been suggested *many* times. And thanks for editing the title. I mistakenly thought that I already did that.

Comment: Some other SE and SO sites have features that this one does not. The only one I can think of offhand is ips.SE, which has a feature that auto deletes comments if they contain "+1", which I hate. There are other, better features on some sites, but don't ask me to remember them. And I'm *not* suggesting that we should add all kinds of fancy stuff just because we can. But what are our options in that respect?

Comment: My guess is that we still don't have enough activity.

Comment: And if I were to come across ham.SE for the first time, some of the questions might make me shake my head and click off this site.

Comment: I would never shake my head at the _questions_, but at how the questions are answered, or otherwise dealt with. We get our share of questions about CB, which is a subject that traditionally turns hams off - but if they’re about the technology involved, they are cromulent questions. See the recent question about a Cobra CB handheld and its antenna for an example of this. We were all beginners once. It used to be that beginners would start as an SWL or a CBer. Nowadays the internet has made the whole shebang feel obsolete, so we need to treat all users of radio as equals ...